# Why is my saved string returning 6 on "word".size?

Tags: ruby, string

`"word".size` returns `6`, but doing a check with the string for white space with `.match(/\s/)` returns `nil`. What am I not seeing here?

Comment: use `each_byte` to understand what your string is made of: `string.each_byte { |c| puts c }`

Comment: @apneadiving how do I understand what the numbers represent?

Comment: Try `"word".scan(/[[:print:]]/).size`.. Tell me the count.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Here's the byte representation. (For the sake of simplicity I used the string "word" in the question, but it's actually an email-address.)
`102 111 111 64 98 97 114 46 99 111 109`

Comment: If you didn't want to put one of your users' email addresses into your post, you just failed: it's easy to turn that bytearray back into a string and see it (i just did).  I'd recommend you change the email address to be fake, see if the problem recurs, and if so amend your last comment to be the bytes of the fake address.  (even if it doesn't recur you should change your comment)

Comment: Are you sure it is not `'"word"'.size`?

Comment: btw, `<email>.size` gives me 28 which is what I'd expect.

Comment: @BroiSatse You are nice in reasoning... :p

Comment: @BroiSatse How do I find out if it it is like you suggest?

Comment: @Numbers - All depends on how you are calling it. Do you just type it in the console ore are  calling it on some other object? In the former case, call inspect on it.

Comment: @BroiSatse It's a string saved in the db.

Comment: Any non-ascii (UTF?) characters in the string?

Comment: Then call inspect on it - if  you get `"\"word\""` then the quotes are saved in the database.

Comment: @BroiSatse Beutiful, that was it. Thanks a lot!! It would be much appreciated if you created an answer out of your last comment so I can choose it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As resolved in the comments, it is not `"word"` but `'"word"'` - surrounding quotes are part of the string. Couple of ways to prove it:

```
string.inspect    #=> "\"word\""
string[0]         #=> "\""
```